# "That following summer" vs "The following summer"

Tags: meaning, parts-of-speech

> She moved to our school in the middle of her first year in high school. **That following summer**, she asked the coach if she could join the team as a sophomore.

1) What's the meaning difference between 'that following summer' and 'the following summer'? Especially, what meaning does "that" add?

2) What part of speech is 'that' in the "that following summer"? a determiner as in [[that][following]summer] or an adverb as in [[that following] summer]?

Answer (score 1):

1. There is no difference in meaning.
2. The *that* is a definite article (which normally in English is *the*).

[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_(grammar)#Definite_articles):

> The English definite article the, written þe in Middle English, derives from an Old English demonstrative, which, according to gender, was written se (masculine), seo (feminine) (þe and þeo in the Northumbrian dialect), or þæt (neuter). The neuter form þæt also gave rise to the modern demonstrative that.

I'd put it down to preference.

Answer (score 0):

Both are fine and mean the same thing. *That* is sometimes a storyteller's affectation. But it doesn't have to be.